# How can I print on a steel tube without resorting to vinyl wraps?

Tags: background, print-production

I am looking to print a background graphic onto a 2m long steel tube (40mm diameter). The graphic is a camo design consisting of 4 colours.

Unfortunately vinyl wrap isn't a suitable option for this specific product, so I'm hoping there's some way of digitally printing the graphic all over?

Comment: https://www.pannier.com/industrial-printers/flexographic/offset-pipe-printers/ Maybe???

Comment: Water transfer? Vaccum heat pressed sublimation? Rotary uv printing? Spray painting?